# Powershell Xerox - get printer information

Tags: powershell, printers, xerox

I have a printer in local network and need to get printer counter status like below:

[image]

There is a code that get the printer status (source gitgub - > https://github.com/KyleOndy/Get-Toner) and it works :

```
        $printertype = $SNMP.Get(".1.3.6.1.2.1.25.3.2.1.3.1")
        $raw = $SNMP.gettree("43.11.1.1")
```

$SNMP.gettree return a printer page "Supplies" and I need it to return "Usage counters"

Can someone explain to me how to get this information ?

Much appreciated !

Comment: You just need to find the right SNMP address - that is probably specific to your make/model of hardware. There are various GUI and script tools available to perform an "SNMP Walk" - ie to retrieve each individual value. I would start there.

Comment: This link mentions the Xerox SNMP OID: https://www.reddit.com/r/sysadmin/comments/4trz5m/snmp_oid_for_color_pages_printed/

Comment: Any idea how to do SNMP walk ? and how to do it for specyfic printer ?

Comment: I was able to find it thanks to Remko, thanks !